# ColdFusion and SmartSheet API

Tags: json, api, coldfusion

I'm attempting to call the smartsheet.com api and read the JSON data from a list sheet request.  Im new to API's so I'm certain I'm missing much with my code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<cfscript>
    apiURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets";
    apiToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
</cfscript>

<cfhttp url="#apiURL#" method="GET"  result="httpResp" timeout="120" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #apiToken#" />
</cfhttp>
```

However I do not receive the desired response:

[image: CFDumpImage]

I was attempting to use the sample provided to retrieve the data:

SmartSheet API 2.0
Example Request:

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Example Response:

```
{  
   "pageNumber":1,
   "pageSize":100,
   "totalPages":1,
   "totalCount":2,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "accessLevel":"OWNER",
         "id":4583173393803140,
         "name":"sheet 1",
         "createdAt":"2015-06-05T20:05:29Z",
         "modifiedAt":"2015-06-05T20:05:43Z"
      },
      {  
         "accessLevel":"OWNER",
         "id":2331373580117892,
         "name":"sheet 2",
         "createdAt":"2015-06-05T20:05:29Z",
         "modifiedAt":"2015-06-05T20:05:43Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of CF? Looks similar to this issue: [ColdFusion 9.0.1  -  3574332 CHTTP returns filecontent as java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream when mimetype is application/json](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3574332). The workaround is to either:

- Set the CFHTTP attribute `getasbinary="never"` OR
- Convert the returned `fileContent` object into a string using:

  ```
   <cfset rawJSONString = httpResp.fileContent.toString()>
  ```

Comment: Spot on Leigh!  Yes I am running CF 9.0.1.  Thank you!